# Why the animation of push another view controller goes not smooth?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-animation

I got a table View and collection view on the each cell.
When I tapped the cell, following code will be invoked in cell's `didSelectRowAt:IndexPath` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        navigationController?.pushViewController(anotherViewController(), animated: true)

    }
```

The `anotherViewController` is an empty view controller on storyboard for now. It only print "I'm coming" in `viewDidLoad()`.
**Here is the problem:**
When I touched the cell, the push animation seems got stuck, pleas check the following GIF.
I'm really confused in what's happend.
Feel free to give any Advice.

The following Image shows the view hierarchy.
Cells on the table view.
Collection view and other components on the cell's content view.
At the end, image views on the collection view's content view.

[image: View Hierarchy]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the animated to true and see the effect?

Comment: Check what you have done in next viewcontroller's `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` methods.

Comment: @user1000 Sorry for that, the GIF shows the animation, which is exactly my problem. I tried to set animated to false to see what could happen. As you could image, problem is gone, because there is no animation..... I forgot to change it back. I've changed it to true now, thanks.

Comment: @YunCHEN I just set the `viewDidLoad()` methods and print "I'm coming".

Comment: did you try this in real device ?

Comment: @KKRocks I've tried. It's the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem rests in the `anotherViewController()` reference. I was even able to reproduce the problem when I pushed to a `UIViewController` instance:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(UIViewController(), animated: true)
```

But when I instantiate a scene from a storyboard, that worked fine. Obviously, you need a scene with the appropriate storyboard identifier:

```
let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Details")
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Or, if I defined segue between the two view controllers and performed the segue, that also worked:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailsSegue", sender: self)
```

Comment: I guess simply call `UIViewController()` doesn't initialize the controller properly.  The GIF shows the background color of destination view controller is totally black. But the view controller initialized from storyboard has white background color. Thank your. You help me a lot.

Answer (score 8):

The solution for me was to explicitly set the background color of the new view controller, even if it's black.
I had the same issue and since I'm not using storyboard, this was the solution for me.

Comment: Very weird, but this solution did work for me. Had this issue in iOS = 10, worked fine in iOS>10 though without this hack.
Good catch :))

Comment: This works... but why?